# how to center header names in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How to center header names in Microsoft Power BI? I tried to find it in Visualization pane in Headers section with no success. The headers are left aligned while the figures are right aligned.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm presuming you are using a Table visual.

You set this per-column.  In the Visualizations pane, look for **Field Formatting**, choose each required field, set **Alignment**, turn on **Apply to header** .